# SQL query against Excel worksheet not working

Tags: sql, excel

Using the connection string

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\SamaanTree\Documents\Institutional_Data\Institutional.xlsm;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1";
```

I am querying a worksheet using the SQL query below to split a string that has "|" as a separator. The query, such as it is below, works fine

```
SELECT  
    [Institution], 'Body', NULL, 4, 
    LEFT([USER_ID], INSTR([User_Id], '|')) AS [Info_Q],
    RIGHT([USER_ID], LEN([USER_ID]) - INSTR([User_Id], '|')) AS [Info_A], 
    [Active], NULL
FROM    
    [Institution_Data$]
WHERE   
    LEN([USER_ID]) > 0
```

However, I need to decrement (by 1) the position returned by the INSTR function for [Info_Q] and as soon as I amend the script to

```
SELECT  
    [Institution], 'Body', NULL, 4, 
    LEFT([USER_ID], INSTR([User_Id], '|') - 1) AS [Info_Q],
    RIGHT([USER_ID], LEN([USER_ID]) - INSTR([User_Id], '|')) AS [Info_A], 
    [Active], NULL
FROM    
    [Institution_Data$]
WHERE   
    LEN([USER_ID]) > 0
```

I get an error

> Data provider or other service returned an E_FAIL status

Any pointers\answers would be most welcome.

Also, is there a list of valid SQL functions that can be used for this type of script?

Comment: I'd guess left(user_ID,x-1) when instr(user_ID) Returns 0 is your problem.  so `left(user_ID,0-1)` is probably throwing the error.    some record either doesn't have a | or the system is evaluating a null and trying to get a left of it.  ... maybe use `case when (instr([user_ID],'|') > 0 then LEFT([USER_ID], INSTR([User_Id], '|')) else [User_ID] end`

Comment: Thank you for the response. There are Nulls in the column but these are being eliminated by the WHERE clause. I had previously replaced the Nulls with appropriate dummy values to test that very point but it did not resolve the issue